# white screen after the splash screen in android studio

Tags: java, android

Overview-

A white screen appears after the splash activity every time I launch the app, I have tried many solutions but nothing has worked out if anyone knows the solution please help!
Thanks!

```
enter code here-
```

manifest file-

```
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
        <activity android:name=".splash_activity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"></activity>
    </application>
```

```
enter code here-
```

XML file-

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    </style>


</resources>
```

```
    enter code here-
java file-
package com.cnc.cncapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;

public class splash_activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Handler mHandler;
    private  Runnable mRunnable;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_activity);

        mRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
            }
        };

        mHandler = new Handler();
        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable,2000);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        if(mHandler!=null && mRunnable!=null){
            mHandler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);
        }
    }
}
```

enter code here-

```
Main activity-
package com.cnc.cncapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView mywebView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mywebView=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        mywebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        mywebView.loadUrl("https://www.cncrooms.in/");
        WebSettings webSettings=mywebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    }
    public class mywebClient extends WebViewClient{
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon){
            super.onPageStarted(view,url,favicon);
        }
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view,String url){
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed(){
        if(mywebView.canGoBack()) {
            mywebView.goBack();
        }
        else{
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

```
enter code here-
```

```
layout file-
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    tools:context=".splash_activity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="228dp"
        android:layout_height="209dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="91dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="91dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="261dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="92dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="92dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="261dp"
        android:src="@drawable/rsz_sitelogo"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </ImageView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

```
enter code here
```

```
Main Activity layout file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: also, post your `MainActivity.java` class

Comment: Post your layout file

Comment: I have added both the layout and main activity file as well

Comment: what exactly are you expecting ,and is the other activity opening and not loading the url or is it not opening at all ?and is the white screen staying for long or is it for afew seconds ? is the app hanging (prompting the user to wait or close)?do you have internet permissions?

Comment: Yeah the problem is that the white screen is staying for long, yes I do have the internet permissions@Thompsonsparta

Comment: Can you post your MainActivity layout file? The issue appears to be entirely to do with MainActivity and nothing to do with your splash screen or the transition to the MsinActivity.

Comment: I have added the main activity layout file please check now @codebod

Comment: Inner class `mywebClient` doesn't appear to be initialized. Replace `new WebViewClient()` with `new mywebClient()`? Can I also suggest changing the name of this inner class to title case, i.e. `MyWebClient`, to improve readability.

Comment: Not helping problem is still there @codebod